# How to fix gradient computation error by inplace operation in torch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I read the paper below, and wrote the implementation code for 'case 1'. Gradient computation error by inplace operation occurs during backpropagation.
[text](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13726)

This paper is about approximating the forces of the physical system using neural networks, and 'case 1' is about '1D system where one force acts'

This is my full code.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
import numpy as np
import math

class adsmodel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, delta_t, t_s, t_f, m, g, max_v, batch_size, c):
        super().__init__()
        self.delta_t=delta_t
        self.m=m
        self.g=g
        self.t_f=t_f
        self.t_s=t_s
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        self.L=max_v+1
        self.c=c
        self.force=nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(np.random.uniform(low=10, high=20, size=(self.L,))))

    def _forward(self, v):
        v_abs=torch.abs(v)
        v_c=torch.ceil(v_abs).type(torch.LongTensor)
        v_f=torch.floor(v_abs).type(torch.LongTensor)
        ans=(v_c-v_abs)*self.force[v_f]+(v_abs-v_f)*self.force[v_c]
        return ans
    
    def forward(self, v):
        for _ in range(int((self.t_f-self.t_s)/self.delta_t)):
            v-=(self.g-(self._forward(v)/self.m))*self.delta_t
        return v
    
    def loss(self, x, y):
        result=self.forward(x)
        regular=0
        for i in range(self.L-1):
            regular+=(self.force[i+1]-self.force[i])*(self.force[i+1]-self.force[i])
        regular*=self.c
        regular+=self.force[0]*self.force[0]
        loss=torch.mean(torch.abs(result-y))+regular
        return loss

def train(epoch, model, train_x, train_y, lr):
    optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    for i in range(epoch):
        print(i)
        loss=model.loss(train_x, train_y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
        
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
        
model=adsmodel(0.1, 0, 4, 1, 9.8, 500, 10, 0.03)
train_x=torch.FloatTensor(np.random.uniform(-100, -10, (10,)))
train_y=torch.FloatTensor(np.random.uniform(-200, -50, (10,)))
print(model.loss(train_x, train_y))

device=torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model=model.to(device)
train_x, train_y=train_x.to(device), train_y.to(device)

train(100, model, train_x, train_y, 0.01)
```

I used the 'torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)' code to find out where the problem is.
And I found out that the problem occurs in the 'ans=(v_c-v_abs)*self.force[v_f]+(v_abs-v_f)*self.force[v_c]' operation of the forward function. But I don't know how to fix this error.

***error message***

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [10]], which is output 0 of SubBackward0, is at version 81; expected version 80 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

Comment: Don't use -=, +=, etc. expressions as these are inplace operations, i.e. they specify that the result should be stored in the same location in memory as the input. This is a problem because the result has a gradient and the input has a gradient, each of which need to be stored in memory for the computation graph to be able to back-propogate correctly. Thus, the allocated memory is overwritten and the gradient cannot be correctly back-propogated. Also, the loop in your loss function should be avoided.

Comment: Also, `torch.abs`, `torch.ceil`, and `torch.floor` are partially non-differentiable and (in the case of the latter 3) have almost entirely a gradient of 0, so will not be useful for parameter optimization. The gradient of a parameter is the partial derivative of the output (or whatever value `backward()` is called on) with respect to that parameter, usually requiring that the parameter is defined over a continuous rather than cardinal (integer) range.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix the problem thanks to your advice